Using a variable to set a userform object name
I am working on a specific project where I need to loop through a set of user form objects and do something to each of them (in the case it’s a label). I have them named lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, … so on and so forth. I need to find a way to loop through and toggle the visibility of them with my loop.
I have tried the following to no avail:
(This is an incomplete portion of the code only using the relevant information)
Dim i as Long
Dim result as Object

'… ‘code to define what i is

Set result = “lbl & i 
'… ‘ more code to continue the loop


You can utilize Controls collection. Give a try-
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 3
        Me.Controls("lbl" & i).Visible = False
    Next

End Sub

You can also use Set method. Then it would be like-
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim lb As Object

    For i = 1 To 3
        'Me.Controls("lbl" & i).Visible = False
        Set lb = Controls("lbl" & i)
        lb.Visible = False
    Next

End Sub

You can also declare variable as Control like Dim lb As Control.
